# Sync MP3 Ratings on Android, with MediaMonkey / MusicBee on Windows

Tags: sync, music, music-player, mp3, mp3-player

Both MediaMonkey and MusicBee, as music players let you 'rate' songs from 1 to 5 stars.  I would like to have this functionality as well in an Android app.  The main problem is syncing these ratings.  Android apps like NRG Player do have a rating, however if I rate songs using NRG Player, they are not 'understood' by neither MediaMonkey nor MusicBee.  Also, any ratings I give to songs via MediaMonkey or MusicBee are neither understood by the NRG Player.

Is there any app which reads/writes ratings in the same format that either MediaMonkey or MusicBee do?  Or any app which syncs such ratings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I posted this question, I found out that 'PlayerPro' music player allows you to choose the type of ratings it saves to.  MediaMonkey is one of them, so this basically is what I needed. Unfortunately, it is not a free app, but for me although this is a tiny feature, this is something I'm willing to pay for.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, I'd recommend: Use Media Monkey on your desktop and PlayerPro on your Android mobile. 
And if you change ratings or other data while listening to music on mobile (PlayerPro), then export the Music ratings etc in a Songbird XML file (from within PlayerPro>Settings> Music Library> Export Ratings in songbird format) in the mobile and copy that XML file generated to any one particular location on your pc. Then get a MM script named 'Import Music Stats XML' for MMWindows and execute that command from the tools menu. It'll ask for the songbird XML file location and that's it. Both MM and PP will remain in synch. You can change anything in any of these.

Also, if you want to sync/send your chosen media files from PC to Mob automatically, then install MM on your android mobile also, and then you can transfer your chosen music to mob with 1 simple click/synch command. (you can sync the music back to PC also, but then your PP ratings and play count won't sync back. In this case, your android's ratings and play count will synch back to PC).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer

You can do this with [Media Monkey remote app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.erlenddahl.mmremotefree&hl=en)

Comment: That doesn't let you play songs on your Android phone.  It lets you see what is playing on the desktop, and control it via your phone.  While this is extremely cool and I will certainly be using it - What I need is a music player for Android, which will allow me to play music and rate them *on the phone*, and then I can copy them back to the PC and the ratings are read by MediaMonkey.